# Software for creating a 3D planet

Tags: planets, astronomy, worldbuilding-resources, map-making, software-recommendations

(Sorry for my English, it's not my native language. I use Google translate.)

I am looking for one or more software programs to create a sphere in 3D with longitudes, latitudes, etc. I want to be able to rotate this sphere, implant a texture, tell what’s hot and cold, and more.

Comment: This is not an answer, just a helpful comment: there are many and varied worldbuilding resources in [this post](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/143606/a-list-of-worldbuilding-resources) which you may find useful.

Comment: [LunarCell](http://flamingpear.com/lunarcell.html) renders in photoshop and exports maps for 3D software.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A list of worldbuilding resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/143606/a-list-of-worldbuilding-resources)

Answer (score -2):

I've seen things about certain websites that let you make a planet, specifically http://planetmaker.wthr.us/